# CMake Release build on Windows takes hours more than Debug

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

When trying to build a library under Windows via the `cmake --build` command, the Release configuration takes 6 times as long as the debug configuration.

Specifically, this is for the [GTSAM library](https://github.com/borglab/gtsam). The Debug config takes about 30 minutes, but the Release config takes over 2 hours (sometimes 3).

The CI we use is Github Actions and the workflow definition can be found [here](https://github.com/borglab/gtsam/blob/develop/.github/workflows/build-windows.yml).
Any help please?

Comment: Maybe the Release config is doing more work: optimizations, code-analysis, profiling, etc. (I know my *final* release builds - which I call "Publish" - take much longer than any others.)

Comment: It also looks like your release builds are getting paused for exactly one hour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJDuQ.png (the raw logs have timestamps), so you might be hitting some kind of soft usage cap (or getting preempted) in the free runners